# Index of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

a) What is the index of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

b) prove that if $a\in\mathbb{C}^*$, then exists $b\in\mathbb{C}^*$ such that $|b|=1$ and $b\mathbb{R}_+^*=a\mathbb{R}_+^*$

My solution is
a) for a $x$ real and a complex $z=a+bi$, we have $z+x=(a+x)+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ and since $z$ is arbitrary, the index is infinite.

b) **(where I'm stuck)** if $a=|a|e^{i\alpha}$, then for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^*$, we can write

$$bx=|a|^{i\alpha}y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b=\frac{|a|y}{x}e^{i\alpha} $$

But I am not sure that $|b|=1$.

Comment: I don't really understand how you conclude that the index is infinite from that equality. The index is infinite, because $z+\mathbb{R}=z'+\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $z-z'\in\mathbb{R}$ which is if and only if $z$ and $z'$ have equal imaginary part. And the result follows since there are infinitely many choices for the imaginary part.

Comment: I like that $\Bbb R \in \Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $b=\frac a{|a|}$. Then $|b|=1$ and, since $|a|\in\Bbb R_+^*$, $b\Bbb R_+^*=a\Bbb R_+^*$.

Comment: Obrigado professor. Do you agree with my item (a) solution?

Comment: I think the the index is infinite because $b$, rather than $z$, is arbitrary.

Comment: I made a mess... It is really because of $b$